# When using iScroll with inputs in iOS safari the keyboard pushes the scroller above the viewport and get stuck

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, iscroll

Has anyone figure out how to solve this? I talked to Matteo from Cubiq and his solution was to use transitions instead of transforms. Right now, im essentially adding padding the size of the keyboard below the page when the keyboard comes up, but that has a bunch of new issues revolving around the cursor being messed up:

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input, textarea', function() {
                console.log('SCROLLER INPUT FOCUS');
                if(!self.getCurrentScroller()) return;
                self.getCurrentScroller().css('padding-bottom', 260);
                self.getCurrentIscroll().refresh();
                self.getCurrentIscroll().scrollToElement(this, 0);
            });

            $('body').on('blur', 'input, textarea', function() {
                console.log('SCROLLER INPUT BLUR');
                if(!self.getCurrentScroller()) return;
                self.getCurrentScroller().css('padding-bottom', 0);
                self.getCurrentIscroll().refresh();
                self.getCurrentIscroll().scrollToElement(this, 0);
            });
```

the idea is that the keyboard only causes iScroll to get stuck above the viewport if you're at the bottom of iscroll and there is no more page to scroll when the keyboard pushes it up.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes virtual keyboard causes physical sroll to change. So that you might scroll it to top when keyboard hides.

```
$wrapper.find('input, textarea').on('blur', function (e) {
    $wrapper.scrollTop(0);
});
```